# Sagemath: `a = -1.0; (a)^(1/3)` returns a complex number

Tags: math, sage

Running the following snippet:

```
a = -1.0
show(a^(1/3))
```

Gives me the (unexpected) result:

```
0.500000000000000+0.866025403784439i
```

But, running the following:

```
show(-1.0^(1/3))
```

Gives me the expected result `−1.00000000000000`.

Is this expected behavior? Am I misunderstanding what computation I'm asking for?

Comment: The second version is equivalent to `-(1.0^(1/3))` because unary minus has a lower precedence than exponentiation.

Comment: and the first result is actually correct (or rather, one of the three correct answers)

Comment: The number -1 has three cube roots, and this is one of them. Please also see https://ask.sagemath.org/question/53481/imaginary-result-for-cube-root-of-1/.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha returns the [same value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5E%281%2F3%29) for the first one, which is the [principal value](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeRoot.html) of the cube root.

Comment: The simplest check is to simply cube the answer you get.

Comment: @kaya3: Want to put that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version calculates the principal cube root of -1, which is a complex number.

In the second version, the expression `-1.0^(1/3)` is equivalent to `-(1.0^(1/3))`, because the unary negation operator has a lower precedence than exponentiation; so it calculates the cube root of 1, and then negates it.